# Fullscreen issues in Microsoft Edge browser?

Tags: css, video, fullscreen, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm having some issues with fullscreen video in the Edge browser on Windows 10. Currently my video elements are using the HTML5 video player, but I don't think that's the problem because two different video elements of mine (that use the same video player) produce different results when going into fullscreen, both with identical views (MVC) as well. Could this be a CSS issue? Is there some sort of Microsoft Edge prefix I'm not taking into consideration? I'm not really sure why one would work and not the other?

Here is a screenshot of the fullscreen that I currently get with the broken video element.

[image]

The red indicates the video, the white is just white and the black is just what is behind the video. Normally the play/fullscreen/pause button would be along the lower black edge.

Comment: which Win10 build do you use?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible code snippet via jsbin (or another service)?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine now (Build 10162). maybe in the previous builds there were some issues. you can check a working demo here on this link: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video